# How can I boot a Live CD on laptop with broken internal hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, livecd, liveusb

My laptop’s internal hard drive is broken, and while there is an SSD, it is 22GB capacity and is also not the boot drive. Whenever I try to boot from a Live CD (ParrotOS) it loops an I/O error (blk_update_request) and eventually stops with “BOOT FAILED!” even though I want nothing to do with that drive.

My laptop is a Thinkpad S230u, which I don’t know the specs of offhand.

I just need to know if I can somehow boot without it attempting whatever its doing on the broken drive. I have an issue right now that I can only solve with ParrotOS and don’t have access to anything else today.

EDIT: I don’t know if this is important, but the terminal also inconsistently says “mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /run/live/medium failed: invalid argument”, maybe this is because I took everything out of boot order save for the live cd? I’ll put it back at the bottom and report back.

EDIT2: Restoring hdd, ssd, and others to the bottom of the boot order made no difference. Also, switching the Live CD to a different USB port made no difference as well.

Comment: Your live burnt CD might be corrupted and can have unreadable data sectors. Check the integrity of the Downloaded ISO. You can try re burning the ISO into an USB flash drive. Check if the SSD or broken HDD does not have a greater priority in UEFI or BIOS. Try to change The SATA mode to AHCI.

Comment: I actually removed everything but the Live CD from boot priority after the hdd broke, and it doesn’t make sense my Live CD would be corrupt when it was working perfectly fine earlier (not that it’s impossible). The blk_update_request references only /dev/sdb, which is my broken hdd. EDIT: I looked at the SATA mode setting, it was already on AHCI. I tried the only other option “compatibility”, there was no difference. Still loops blk_update_request.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect all your internal drives and try to boot your live CD.
Then try to boot again adding one drive after another to search the culprit that prevents booting.

The best thing is to remove your broken drive and connect it to a running linux system to see if it is recognized there.